# How to Initilize a DataGridView and add Columns to it?

Tags: c#, .net

I can make a `Button` like this:

```
    Button buttonMinimize = new Button()
    {
        Size = new Size(40, 10),
        BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,
        Location = new Point(10,10),
        TabStop = false,
    };
```

If I want to make a `DataGridView` in a same way: (see comments in code, the problem is there)

```
    DataGridView Passage = new DataGridView()
    {
        Columns = ??!//what should I write here to set my columns?
        //since Columns is a readonly property

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

DatagridviewColumn is what you want http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.aspx

Comment: `DataGridView.Columns` is a `DataGridViewColumnCollection`

Comment: Aah, sorry mis-understood the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an option to add columns in this way. Add them one by one.

```
passageGridView.Columns.Add("ColumnName", "ColumnHeader");
```

Comment: I know this option, I want to add them the way I explained